# Passing a pointer by value - allocating memory in the function

Tags: c++

When I want to assign a memory to the pointer in the function I have to pass the pointer by reference (or pointer), for example:

```
void fun(int*& ptr) //or int** ptr
{
    ptr = new int(1); 
}

int* ptr = nullptr;
fun(ptr);
int x = *ptr;
```

I have noticed that when I have a struct which contains a pointer passing by value works:

```
struct T
{
    int* ptr{ nullptr };
};

void fun(T* t)
{
    t->ptr = new int(1);
}

T *t = new T{};
fun(t);
int x = *(t->ptr);
```

Could you explain why in the second case I don't have to pass a pointer to the struct by reference or pointer ?

Comment: What makes you think that `void fun(T* t)` is passing T by value? You are passing a pointer to T. Change your code to `void fun(T t)` and you'll find it doesn't work again.

Comment: The fundamental issue here is that if you want to change something in a function, you have to pass a reference or a pointer to that something. You can wrap the something in a struct and then pass a pointer to the struct (like you are doing), that will work. And please note (this is what really confuses people) it makes no difference at all what the something is, it could be a pointer, it could be an integer, its all the same. But for some reason people think that when the something is itself a pointer, the rules are different, they are not.

Comment: "What makes you think that void fun(T* t) is passing T by value?" Here the pointer is passed by value.

Comment: Yes but you have two pointers, and the pointer you are trying to change is **not** being passed by value. You are in effect passing a pointer to the pointer you are trying to change, and that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are trying to return to the caller is `int*`. Using a typedef should help:

```
using IntPtr = int*;

void fun(IntPtr& ptr) // works
{
    ptr = new int;
}
void fun(IntPtr* ptr) // works
{
    *ptr = new int;
}
void fun(IntPtr ptr) // won't work
{
    ptr = new int;
}

struct Foo
{
    IntPtr ptr;
};

void fun(Foo& foo) // works
{
    foo.ptr = new int;
}
void fun(Foo* foo) // works
{
    foo->ptr = new int;
}
void fun(Foo foo) // won't work
{
    foo.ptr = new int;
}
```